# No Attribute 'method' in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have multiple forms on one page and my view is handling these by checking the value of the submit. This seems to work all fine, however on of my forms is getting the error below.

```
'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'method'
```

VIEW

```
def all(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'all' in request.POST['submit']:
        all(request.POST)
    elif 'addtype' in request.POST['submit']:
        addtype(request.POST)
    elif 'addnewpm' in request.POST['submit']:
        addnewpm(request.POST)
    elif 'addnewspec' in request.POST['submit']:
        addnewspec(request.POST)
    elif 'update' in request.POST['submit']:
        update(request.POST)
    elif 'addnewrecord' in request.POST['submit']:
        addnewrecord(request.POST)
```

Basically I am just passing the post values to seperate functions based on which submit button was pressed. They all work fine except for the first one 'all'. The 'all' submit button is submitting a large amount of data, and I can see all this data in the traceback.

Maybe it has something to do with my HTML code.

```
<table class="gridtable">
<tr>
<td class="topheader-left" colspan="10">     
<form action="" method="post">
<button type="submit" value="all" name="submit" style="border:0px;">
<img src="{%  get_static_prefix %}images/update.png" style="width:27px;height:27px;">
</button>
</td>
</tr>
```

Below this I just have a large number of table cells with fields and a /form at the end.

The code from one of the forms on my page that works fine.

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<form method="post" action="">
<td>
<input id="newtype" type="text" name='newtype' size="40" value="Service Type">
</td>
<td>
<button name="submit" type="submit" value="addtype" style="border:0px;">
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/Add-icon.png" width="20" height="20" border="0">
</button>
</td>
</form>
```

This form seems to work fine. I don't understand what I am doing differently.

Cheers guys.

Comment: Looks like you're recursively calling the `all()` function with `request.POST` as the argument on the second call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a simple function name collision. Your view method name is `all` and you're calling `all(request)` again and again, and again :) if the value of `submit == all`.

Using `in` to look for the value of submit in request.POST seems odd. Why not just set the value once and compare it that way?

```
submit = request.POST['submit']

if submit == 'all':
    # call method
elif submit == 'addtype':
   # etc
```

Comment: Hey guys, wow, can't believe I didn't pick that one up, must have been on a totally different wave of thinking. Looks like that has fixed it. Thanks so much.

Comment: No worries. I love when I'm editing the wrong file and wondering why my changes aren't showing up :)

Comment: Haha, Yep, been there, done that, as I expect everybody has :) - cheers